# Telegram Bot - где выгоднее держать

Tags: java, telegram-bot, jar, telegram, бот

Имеется готовый бот телеграм написанный на java (-jar), где выгоднее его держать? на VPS сервере слышал можно, но где есть пробный период хотя бы?, или более менее бесплатный VPS?, чтобы можно было разместить java бота.

Comment: Heroku: Cloud Application Platform

Comment: @Виктор Heroku больше под вэб заточено, чем под jar

Comment: напиши на spring и залей на heroku, выкладывание не бесплатные сервисы упирается в SSL сертификат, который heroku, в отличии от других выдает